# SQL - How to get Distinct Values from a Column that are Unique to an Entry in another Column?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, toad, relational

I work in a factory that makes Microchips. We make these Microchips in Batches of 10,000.
One of the Machines that the Microchip Batches are processed on is called 'Dispense'.
There are 30 of these 'Dispense' machines - named Dispense 1, Dispense 2, Dispense 28 etc.

These Machines often 'Alarm' if there is an issue when processing the Microchips.
The different Alarms are assigned different 'Codes'.

So Alarm Code 1 may be 'Kill Switch left on'.
Alarm Code 2 may be 'Guard Door still open' etc.

In an ideal World, All Dispense Machines would have the same suite of Alarm Codes.
But they don't.

They are certain Alarm Codes that are Unique to Dispense 1 for example, that do not occur on the other Dispense machines.

The Alarms data is fed into a table called 'dispense_status' like the below:

| machine | alarm_code | run_timestamp | batch_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dispense_1 | 1 | 23-07-2021 14:32 | 1000585855 |
| Dispense_23 | 4 | 12-09-2021 12:34 | 1000585856 |
| Dispense_9 | 7 | 11-08-2021 13:33 | 1000456789 |
| Dispense_1 | 2 | 09-09-2021 15:55 | 1000223774 |
| Dispense_9 | 2 | 18-05-2021 12:34 | 1000374590 |

In the above Table, Alarm Code 1 is unique to Dispense 1.
Alarm Code 2 occurs on Dispense 1 also, but it is not unique to Dispense 1, as this alarm_code also occurs on Dispense 9.

If I write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ALARM_CODE
FROM DISPENSE_STATUS
WHERE MACHINE = DISPENSE_1
ORDER BY ALARM_CODE
```

This will give me:

| alarm_code |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

But I only want Alarm Code 1, as this is the only Alarm Code unique to Dispense 1.

(Alarm Code 2 also occurs on Dispense 9).

What is a SQL query to give me only Alarm Codes unique to Dispense 1?

Comment: Do you need to know which machine each "unique" alarm code is associated with, or you literally just want to know the "unique" alarm codes?

Comment: Please, take a look: https://dbfiddle.uk/44We4JE9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a HAVING clause to check if it occurs on more than one machine, and check if that occurence is unique to that specific machine:

```
SELECT alarm_code
FROM dispense_status
GROUP BY alarm_code
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT machine) = 1 AND MAX(machine) = 'Dispense_1'
ORDER BY alarm_code;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a SQL query with a subquery to compare Alarm Codes for Dispense_1 with those of other machines:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ds1.ALARM_CODE
FROM DISPENSE_STATUS ds1
WHERE MACHINE = 'Dispense_1'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM DISPENSE_STATUS ds2
    WHERE ds2.ALARM_CODE = ds1.ALARM_CODE
    AND ds2.MACHINE != 'Dispense_1'
);
```

We start with a SELECT DISTINCT statement to retrieve the unique Alarm Codes for Dispense_1.
We use NOT EXISTS in a subquery to check for any other records (ds2) with the same Alarm Code but on a different machine. If there are no such records, it means the Alarm Code is unique to Dispense_1.

Comment: [Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat forgotten feature, `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT ALARM_CODE FROM DISPENSE_STATUS WHERE MACHINE = 'DISPENSE_1'
EXCEPT
SELECT ALARM_CODE FROM DISPENSE_STATUS WHERE MACHINE <> 'DISPENSE_1'
```